# Using converter to a TextBlock in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm binding a collection of strings using an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
     <ItemsControl.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
          </ControlTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.Template>
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding, Converter={local:MyTextConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

The code above does not compile because of the syntax `{Binding, Converter=...}`, how can I use the converter in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You would usually declare the converter as resource and do a StaticResource lookup:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyTextConverter x:Key="MyTextConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource MyTextConverter}}" />
```

---

You could make the other syntax work if your converter would derive from `MarkupExtension` and override the `ProvideValue` method. But this isn't common practice.

```
public class MyTextConverter: MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to using `Converter="{StaticResource YourConverterKey}"` with `YourConverterKey` was declared in your resource like this:

```
<Local:MyTextConverter x:Key="YourConverterKey"></Local:MyTextConverter>
```